# Simple Django app deployed on Azure App Service keeps showing application error

Tags: python, django, docker, azure-web-app-service

[image]

It keeps showing an error after the app has been successfully deployed on the Azure App Service, has anyone experienced something similar to this?

I have tried SSH into it to confirm my files are intact and they are all right, was expecting the default index page I built for the application

- Here are the logs:
  2024-03-02T16:09:02.869Z INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container testlive_0_f3462e59 for site testlive
  2024-03-02T16:09:22.131Z ERROR - Container testlive_0_f3462e59 for site testlive has exited, failing site start
  2024-03-02T16:09:22.144Z ERROR - Container testlive_0_f3462e59 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8000, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
  2024-03-02T16:09:22.184Z INFO  - Stopping site testlive because it failed during startup.

Comment: what do the logs show?

Comment: Please share your code repro.

Comment: I have edited it to show the logs

Comment: Here is the code repo https://github.com/MicahelE/djangolaunch

Answer (score 0):

I tried deploying a Django app to Azure App Service.

First, install the django using pip

```
pip install django
```

Create your Django project:

```
django-admin startproject yourprojectname
```

```
cd yourprojectname
```

Create a virtual environment for the app

```
py -m venv .venv
.venv\scripts\activate
```

Here, you need to create a requirements.txt file to list all the dependencies required for the project.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

Install dependencies:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Run the app :

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Ensure your `wsgi.py` correctly sets the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to 'yourproject.settings' and also ensure your project structure is consistent. Make sure your packages are up to date.

**manage.py**

```py
import os
import sys

def main():

    settings_module = 'project.production' if 'WEBSITE_HOSTNAME' in os.environ else 'project.settings'
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', settings_module)

    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the content of my **settings.py** file

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

SECRET_KEY = 'secretkey'

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = [

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'hello_azure',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    # Add whitenoise middleware after the security middleware
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'project.wsgi.application'


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}



AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATICFILES_DIRS = (str(BASE_DIR.joinpath('static')),)
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')


DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Local output :

[image]

[image]

I deployed the Django app to Azure App Service using the VS Code Azure Extension.

Here are the steps:

1. Select your Azure subscription.
2. Then, select your created web app.
3. Right-click on the web app; you can see the "Deploy to Web App" option.

[image]

[image]

The deployment to azure app service was successful.

To view the website in the browser, right-click on your Azure app service and select **Browse Site**.

[image]

To check the deployed files in azure

1.Open you're Azure app service.

2. Search for Advanced Tools and click on it.
3. Afterward, click on Go.

[image]

[image]

4.Inside the wwwroot folder of the site, you can find your deployed files.

[image]

Here's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to sort it out, for my start gunicorn command I was writing gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --chdir /mysite mysite.wsgi instead of gunicorn --bind=0.0.0.0 --timeout 600 --chdir ./mysite mysite.wsgi